# How to force refresh URL data in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to fetch data every two minutes from an URL, tried different methods to achieve this, couldn't succeed.

```
=if(Minute(Now())=Minute(Now()),
 ImportHtml("https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10006&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=7&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17",
 "table",1),"")
```

Tried above formula, still not updating data.
Need help on this.

Answer (score 1):

this could do the trick... put `=NOW()` in some cell and setup an update rate in settings:

[image]

Comment: referred a cell which has `=now()` function but not working https://snag.gy/zKgX2e.jpg

Answer (score 1):

```
function getData() { 
  var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("<sheet-name>"); 
  var queryString = Math.random(); 
  var cellFunction = '=IMPORTHTML("<url>?","table",<index>)';

    sheetName.getRange('<import-cell>').setValue(cellFunction); 
}
```

- Replace  with the name of your sheet (the tab name, not the name of the file).
- Replace  with the URL of your web page.
- Replace  with the table position on the page, e.g. 1.
- Replace  with the cell where you want to put your import statement, e.g. A1.

Now make a trigger for `getData()` to run in each minute.

It will write the IMPORTHTML command every time in the cell in every minute.